# How to upload XML file data in android emulator of more than 1.2Mb

Tags: android

I want to load a single XML file of 1.2Mb in  android through assets folder as raw file. I heard that there is a limitation in android of 1Mb for a single xml file. How can I get rid of it? Is there any option to overcome this issue?

Comment: @Daniel, Praween k has done neither ;)

Answer (score 4):

First, don't use `assets/` for XML, if your intention is to use it in your application. Use `res/xml/`, as parsing will be about ten times faster, and will also take up less space.

Then, I would simply try it with your file and see if it blows up. I know there is a limit, but I do not know what the threshold size is.

If it blows up, you will either need to split it into multiple files (each with a subset of your data), or not package it with the application, instead downloading it from a server on first run of your appl.